# Page does not work right on iphone but works on other mobile devices

Tags: html, css, ios, responsive

My page does not work on iPhone. I think problem is about the grid layouts but whatever I did I could not fix it.

**This is emulation of my page for

iPhone X : https://prnt.sc/s1v2bo 

iPhone 8 : https://prnt.sc/s1v2u0

But it doesn't work on my phone (iPhone 8) 

It seems like this : https://prnt.sc/s1v3wy**

I researched so much about that , also I added this code too.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0>"`

This page works except with iPhone. 

I tried on Samsung A50 and it works.

It does not work on iPhone X too. There is a problem that about the iPhone.

**Problem is it works normal in Chrome and Opera mobile emulators with original resolutions. But in iPhone , i can not understand what is a problem.**

This is the media query codes :

`````
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) and (device-width: 375px),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    html {
        zoom: 85% !important;
    }
    .letter {
        border-right: 2.95px solid rgb(250, 72, 72);
        border-left: 2.95px solid rgb(250, 72, 72);
        border-bottom: 2.95px solid rgb(250, 72, 72);
    }
    .container-fluid {
        font-size: 12px !important;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        width: 441px !important;
        zoom: 100% !important;
        height: 50px !important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        width: 375px !important;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        width: 441px !important;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        width: 375px !important;
    }
    div.animation-body {
        margin-left: -45px !important;
        margin-top: 221px !important;
        width: 430px !important;
        height: 50px !important;
        border-bottom: 175px solid rgb(250, 72, 72);
        border-top: 175px solid white;
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
    .product .description {
        margin-left: 15px !important;
    }
    #sag-ust-sepet {
        left: 320px !important;
        margin-top: -40px !important;
        font-size: 20px !important;
    }
    .design-carts-buckets {
        font-size: 50px !important;
    }
    #design-card-1 {
        border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        zoom: 38%;
        margin-top: 110px !important;
        margin-left: -190px !important;
        width: 502px !important;
    }
    #design-card-1 .product__info {
        margin-left: 550px !important;
        width: 500px !important;
    }
    #design-card-1 .photo-container {
        margin-left: 30px !important;
        width: 500px !important;
        height: 550px !important;
    }
    #design-card-1 .photo-container img {
        margin-left: 18% !important;
        top: 20px !important;
    }
    /********************************/
    #design-card-2 {
        border-left: 0px !important;
        border-right: 700px solid;
        border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        zoom: 38%;
        margin-top: 50px !important;
        margin-left: -190px !important;
        width: 502px !important;
    }
    #design-card-2 .product__info {
        margin-left: 550px !important;
        width: 500px !important;
    }
    #design-card-2 .photo-container {
        margin-left: 30px !important;
        width: 500px !important;
        height: 550px !important;
    }
    #design-card-2 .photo-container img {
        margin-left: 18% !important;
        top: 20px !important;
    }
    /************************************/
    #design-card-3 {
        border-left: 0px !important;
        border-right: 700px solid;
        border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        zoom: 38%;
        margin-top: 50px !important;
        margin-left: -190px !important;
        width: 502px !important;
    }
    #design-card-3 .product__info {
        margin-left: 550px !important;
        width: 500px !important;
    }
    #design-card-3 .photo-container {
        margin-left: 30px !important;
        width: 500px !important;
        height: 550px !important;
    }
    #design-card-3 .photo-container img {
        margin-left: 18% !important;
        top: 20px !important;
    }
    /**********************************************/
    #design-card-4 {
        border-left: 0px !important;
        border-right: 700px solid;
        border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        zoom: 38%;
        margin-top: 50px !important;
        margin-left: -190px !important;
        width: 502px !important;
    }
    #design-card-4 .product__info {
        margin-left: 550px !important;
        width: 500px !important;
    }
    #design-card-4 .photo-container {
        margin-left: 30px !important;
        width: 500px !important;
        height: 550px !important;
    }
    #design-card-4 .photo-container img {
        margin-left: 18% !important;
        top: 20px !important;
    }
    /******************************************/
    /*** DESIGN CARTS YUKARIDA */
    .seperator-wrapper .seperator {
        display: none;
    }
    .seperator-wrapper {
        margin-top: -11px;
        margin-left: -45px;
    }
    body {
        background: black !important;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #ust-menu-rdesign {
        display: none;
    }
    #sol-menu {
        height: 390px !important;
        position: static !important;
        margin-top: 56px !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        margin-left: -3px !important;
    }
    .fa-apple {
        margin-left: 2px !important;
    }
    .fa-home {
        margin-left: 1px !important;
    }
    .glyphicon-chevron-down {
        margin-top: -550px !important;
        margin-left: -7px !important;
        z-index: 5;
        height: 50px !important;
    }
    .glyphicon-chevron-up {
        top: 1520px !important;
        left: 47% !important;
        z-index: 5;
    }
    .alert {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .w3-container {
        margin-top: -625px !important;
        padding-top: 0px !important;
    }
    .footer_bottom .row {
        margin-left: 3px !important;
        height: 80px !important;
    }
    .footer_bottom {
        padding: 0px !important;
    }
    .footer_bg {
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }
    div.footer_bottom div.col-lg-6 p {
        font-size: 12px !important;
        margin-left: -55px !important;
        margin-top: 26px !important;
        background: white !important;
        height: 55px !important;
        line-height: 50px !important;
        width: 502px !important;
        text-align: center !important;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold !important;
    }
}


/* IPHONE 8 */

@media only screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .glyphicon-chevron-down {
        margin-top: -390px !important;
    }
}


/* IPHONE 8 PLUS */

@media only screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li a {
        float: left !important;
    }
}````
<br>
`````

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Providing code also helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that zoom does not work right in iPhone. I replace zoom method with `transform:scale`. Now problems 80% solved. It is not completely good right now but I think I can fix all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to copy your CSS code and go to

https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Then use the new prefixed code.

Comment: Okay, the problem is only on your iphone8? Other versions works fine?

Comment: No, problem is iPhone. Not the models. I tried on X too. I added to codes in post.

Comment: Why don't you try replacing the device width with (min-width:___px) ? did you try that?

Comment: Yeah, nothing changes on mobile but it breaks desktop resolutions. It is normal in chrome with mobile emulation but does not work in iPhone again. And desktop does not work right too. Because of min-width .

Comment: can you have your source code on codepen or anywhere so I can check and edit some stuff? and if it is online can you give me the link I can test it with my device (Iphone xs)

Comment: http://deneme-site123.byethost5.com/ i uploaded you can check it

Comment: my site does not seem really good here but if you want to check :https://codepen.io/rdslaughter/pen/xxwOXrE

Comment: OK i'll check on it now, but tell me which browser are you using?

Comment: Hi, I think I found what you can do to fix this, try changing your font sizes from px to vw.
for example change your .title h1 font size from 45px to 10vw.
Please try and tell me.

Comment: Okay i converted px to vw with other elements. Do you want me to upload site ? There is nothing wrong in chrome or opera when i look  with emulator. I think everytime i need to upload the site to check on my mobile phone.

Comment: I don't mind re uploading it but I think you should try it out at your side on your mobile too

Comment: It is same :( and desktop is changed right now. Is there any problem with zoom ? I use html { zoom 85%}. And for product cards too. http://rdesign-testv2.byethost33.com/

Comment: It is not about to px or vw . Still same. What can i do ?

Comment: Look it looks normal in chrome https://prnt.sc/s1yrfd  - https://prnt.sc/s1yrie

Comment: the screen shots are from the actual mobile or what? if so then the html is distorted on what browser?

Comment: Screen shots are from desktop. In chrome emulator it looks normal when i set the phone iPhone X. Media queries works right for iPhone resolution. But in phone it changes. HTML is disorted in phone.